# Theorem for showing the eigenvalues of a Jacobian matrix are less than one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

> After having the Jacobian matrix, I want to show whether the eigenvalues of this matrix are less than one or not.

$ J=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & 0 & b \\ 
 c & d & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & e & f \\ 
 g & g & g & h
\end{array}\right) $

(Here $a,b,...,h $ are real constants which all are non-zero)

After finding $\left|J-\lambda I\right|=0$ and simplifying one can get the characteristics polynomial as
$ \lambda^4+(-h-e-d-a)\lambda^3+(ad+ae+ah-bg+de+dh+eh-fg)\lambda^2+(-ade-adh-aeh+afg-bcg+bdg+beg-deh+dfg)\lambda+head-adfg+cgbe-gdbe=0 $

I have tried to find the solutions of the polynomial, and have difficulty to show whether the values are less than one or not.

> Is there any relevant theorem for showing that the eigenvalues (in absolute value) less than one or not (for stability of dynamical system)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without further assumptions you **cannot** conclude that the eigenvalues are less than one in absolute value. For example, if $b = c = f = g = 0$, then the eigenvalues are $a, d, e, h$.